# Firebase Database: 401 for all GET and POST requests using auth version 2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just created a new Firebase app with attached database, and the authentication rules have changed. My database has [rules that allow all reads / writes from the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my database contents:

[image]

Now I'm trying to fetch my data with curl:

```
curl 'https://dhlab-github-metrics.firebaseio.com/hello.json'
```

But this returns:

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after posting I realized I had set the rules section for the "Cloud Firestore", not the "Realtime Database" (note the dropdown!):

[image]

I needed to set my "Realtime Database" rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

And all was well!